# How to align a bootstrap navbar toggle button to the left or right of the brand name?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using a bootstrap navbar in my react app and the code is as follows -

```
 <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="navbar-header">
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03"
            aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <NavLink className="navbar-brand mx-auto" to="/">
            <h4>Crafting Social Minds</h4>
          </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div
          className="collapse navbar-collapse me-auto"
          id="navbarTogglerDemo03"
        >
          <ul className="navbar-nav ms-auto navbar-custom">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
                exact
            
                to="/"
              >
                Organised Events
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
                to="/upcoming-events"
              >
                Upcoming Events
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
             
                to="/new-event"
              >
                New Event
              </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink
                className="nav-link"
               
                to="/about"
              >
                About Us
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {/* <div className="social-part">
            <i className="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i className="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i className="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

For large and medium devices the navbar looks like this -

[image: browser view for large devices]

and for small devices, the same navbar looks as follows-

[image: browser view for small devices]

So, for large(and medium) devices the navbar looks as I was intended, but in the case of small devices, the toggle-navbar button appears above the brand name whereas I want it to appear on the left or on the right of the brand name. Is there any way to fix this without changing the view for large devices using only bootstrap classes?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We don't work with images of code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re using me-auto and ms-auto (margin end and margin start), but those are for Bootstrap 5. Bootstrap 4 uses mr-auto and ml-auto (the tag on your post says bootstrap-4).

If you want the button on the left and your brand name on the right, you should override the normal margin with mr-0 mr-md-3, although with the h4 styling on your name, it just fits on a 320px wide display.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand mr-0 mr-md-3" href="#">
            <h4>Crafting Social Minds</h4>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mr-auto" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Organised Events <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Upcoming Events</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">New Event</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```